# How to measure time it takes for the graph to print

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

Please bear with me as i am quite new to python.

Currently, this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime


start_time = datetime.now()

df = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/aaronhuang/Documents/Desktop/ffp/exfileCLEAN2.csv", skiprows=[1]). 
#replace this with wherever the  file is.

magnitudes = df['Magnitude '].values
times = df['Time '].values
zscores = np.abs(stats.zscore(magnitudes, ddof=1))
outlier_indicies = np.argwhere(zscores > 3).flatten()
print(times[outlier_indicies])


width = 2    #Change this to change the number of ROWS
height = 10    # Change this for number of columns
fig, axes = plt.subplots(width, height, figsize=(30,30))
for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
        x = df.iloc[j*10:(j+1)*10,:]
        axes[i][j].plot(x['Time '], x['Magnitude '])
        axes[i][j].set_xticklabels(x['Time '], rotation=45)
plt.show()


end_time = datetime.now()
print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))
```

Currently, the timer stops when the graph that pops up is manually closed. I would like the timer to stop the moment the graph is printed.

If anyone can help it would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`plt.show(block=False)`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html) which makes `show` return immediately after the window is shown.